React Native (Android) app is crashing with TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'V.current.useContext') since OS updated to masOS Sequoia 15
React Native Android application started crashing when I updated macOS version to Sequoia 15.0,
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'V.current.useContext'), stack:
<unknown>@19:5640
useConsumer@885:300
<unknown>@2349:999
<unknown>@531:3795
 h@2:1788
<unknown>@6:104
h@2:1788
d@2:1179
global code@6188:3
                                                                                                    
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
     at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:257)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:368)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) ```

